# What happend when I call execve() after using dup2() to redirect stdin?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm working on simulate a mini-version of shell. When it comes to execute program with pipe, something makes me confused. I learned fork(), execve(), pipe(), and dup2(). I thought that I can call pipe() to build a unnamed pipe, and fork(), then use dup2() to redirect standard output to the write-side of pipe, use execve() to run the target program. When it comes to the second program, I can redirect standard input to read-side of pipe, and output back to original std-output, then use execve() to run target. But in fact, when I use 'ls -l' as the first program, and 'wc -l' as the second, it failed. However, if the second is 'cat', it works as it's right. So, what happened when I call execve() after using dup2() to redirect stdin? Or there is another problem in my program?

Update: I post some code I use for validate my idea. Here is it.
What's more, I failed to use waitpid() to make sure these things run in sequence.

```
int fd[2];

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int sfd[2];
    sfd[1] = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    sfd[0] = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        char *cmd[] = {
            "/usr/bin/ls", "-l", NULL
        };
        execve("/usr/bin/ls", cmd, envp);
    } else {
        // parent
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        //dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        char *cmd[] = {
            "/usr/bin/wc", "-l", NULL
        };
        execve("/usr/bin/wc", cmd, envp);
    } else {
        // parent
        int status;
        //waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }

    /*pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        char *cmd[] = {
            "/usr/bin/wc", "-l", NULL
        };
        execve("/usr/bin/wc", cmd, envp);
    } else {
        // parent
        int status;
        //waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }*/


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What program? Post some code.

Comment: I have post some. Thx :D

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "it failed"?

If I try I get:

```
/usr/bin/wc: standard input: Input/output error
1
```

That is because `ls` is not in `/usr/bin` on my system:

```
$ which wc cat ls
/usr/bin/wc
/bin/cat
/bin/ls
```

If I fix that, I get:

```
10
```

as my output.

Comment: I have ls in /usr/bin/ :( But that code canot work at my Arch Linux. Confused.